# Rename the [Plimus] tag into [BlueSnap]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process

Stackoverflow has a tag called [plimus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plimus) for the e-commerce service.
BlueSnap bought [plimus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plimus) more than 4 years ago. Please rename the tag accordingly.

Comment: Before anyone does any renaming, some of those questions need to be cleaned up/closed/purged.  Outside of that, the renaming shouldn't be that much effort - it's only a handful of questions.

Comment: I'll work on the cleaning up. I can't create new tags - ah, reputation! - but will flag and edit what I can.